# You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page HomeGraph API

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api, google-developers-console, google-api-console, google-api-explorer

I have had access to this page for a while now. Yesterday for test I had to disable the HomeGraph API and now it is no longer available and does not even show up while searching in the api library

And when I try to access this link [HomeGraph API Details](https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher/details/google/homegraph.googleapis.com?project=gatest-5d940) I get "You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page. " error

[Image to the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0xj9.png)

Any one encountered this before?

I have tried logging out of all my devices

On top of this I starting getting the below while executing gactions -verbose test

Reading credentials from: creds.data
ERROR: Failed to test the app for the Assistant
ERROR: Internal error encountered.
2018/01/06 21:31:52 Server did not return HTTP 200

gaction update works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I just followed [Creating a Smart Home App](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/create-app) docs and went straight to [Request Sync](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/create-app#request-sync). Followed the instructions and created a new project. I made sure I was "Owner" of the project, and had no problem enabling the Home Graph API:

[image]

And here's Home Graph API being enabled:

[image]

Comment: Till yesterday night i could not even search for the homegraph api as I have shown in my first post. This morning it magically appeared again.